# Is it OK to flag a post for moderator review if I'm not sure if it has issues?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, down-votes

Recently one of my flags was rejected, but the rejection message didn't match the flag intention. I was expecting that the moderators reviewed if the post had issues, but the rejection message was about informing downvotes.

---

Recently, given the existing flag reasons didn't seem appropriate to me, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216582/how-call-stack-and-event-loop-interact-or-work-together/73216692#73216692) for moderator intervention, hoping it would be sent for review, since I am not knowledgeable enough to know if the downvote indicated an issue with the answer (therefore needing a fix) or if it was OK and I just happened to encounter a pass-by downvote.

The flag was declined with the reason:

> Please don't inform us about downvotes. People are free to vote however they want and we don't need to be informed of each vote.

Which indicated to me there was likely a miscommunication and that I probably should be handling this case differently. My intention was not to inform or dispute the downvote, but to see if there was an issue that needed fixing.

What should I do in cases like this? What would you do?

To be clear, this situation doesn't apply only to Stack Overflow. In the event that I encounter this situation on any Stack Exchange site, what should I do?

Comment: You should not flag answers just because they have downvotes. This is a terrible waste of the mods time.

Comment: _"the existing flag reasons didn't seem appropriate to me"_ - because there is no need to flag a downvoted answer. A downvote means somebody didn't find it useful or clear.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars it wasn't for the downvote but the downvote informed me it could be an issue with the answer and that's where I wanted to put the focus. I thought having possibly problematic answers reported to be reviewed was welcomed. I thought I was doing something useful giving a part of my time for the community. You could have some empathy towards other users.

Comment: @Adinia If somebody didn't find it useful or clear doesn't that mean it has issues and could be improved? That's what I'm trying to convey to all of you. I don't know why the focus is on the downvote itself.

Comment: @gw0 people who want empathy have other places to go, hopefully. Stack Exchange is place for professional questions and answers, and that is it. Harsh, perhaps, but that's how it works.

Comment: We (here) don't need to know about this, you can use the comments on your question or answer to ask for suggestions for improvement. --- You can read the FAQs and Help files along with their meta (which is not *here*) to find out how things work.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars You can be professional without being rude/mean/unpleasant. Doing so creates resentment among many things and a tense environment. But I guess this isn't the place for me to contribute as you say.

Comment: Well, you make a very common and a very sad mistake that great many people make, with low rep and with high rep. You think that downvotes are toxic, rude, mean, and source of all evil. However, they are not.  I won't go into what they are but I can assure you, nothing here, or with downvotes on SO, is personal. Nobody is against you or hate you, and I'm sorry you feel this way. Really.

Comment: A moderator isn't necessarily going to be able to understand why someone didn't find the answer useful, never mind do anything about it. A down-vote just means _someone_ has an ***opinion*** about the answer. It doesn't mean their opinion is accurate (they could be down-voting the avatar or code formatting or could just be having a bad day), and it doesn't mean there is anything *you* have to do about it, either.

Comment: No idea why people closed this as specific to one site. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Sha, the OP [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384696/282094) an [answer the same as my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384695/what-should-i-do-if-i-come-by-a-downvoted-answer-and-im-not-sure-if-it-has-issu#comment1283283_384695), no need to reopen; it's a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237106/282094 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110242/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280651/282094 and especially: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133275/282094

Comment: @Rob no to all. Big no to leaving closed just because there is answer, and none of the links you gave is duplicate, or even close to it. Some got nothing to do with this question.

Comment: *"You think that downvotes are toxic, rude, mean, and source of all evil.*" @ShadowWizardChasingStars But they don't. They were trying to figure out *why* the answer was down voted, the flag was not a complaint.

Comment: gw0: If you found that people is focusing on a single word that is not the main topic of the post, you might be facing people bias / have found a "behavior trigger". In this specific case of "downvote" we had a lot (some already deleted) posts explicitely or implicitely complaining about the community based moderation model from people having no interest on learning the motivation of such model, more specifically complaing about "downvotes". You might try to remove the that trigger (in this case the word "downvote" or make more emphasis on the real core of the question.

Comment: By the way, questions regarding the moderation model should "always" include a brief description of the local search efforts including links to the most relevant posts and explaining why they were not clear / helpful. (This actually should be done on all questions, even on Meta SE / per-site metas)

Comment: @BSMP you missed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgRoh.png). Keep in mind the only reason OP flag is seeing a downvote. So as far as I understand, they see that downvote as "rude/mean/unpleasant" and to that I commented. Plus, seen way too many similar cases of people considering downvotes source of all evil, so that's nothing new.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars No, I didn't miss it. That comment was in response to you saying, *"...people who want empathy have other places to go..."*, which they understood as you telling them to leave. *"But I guess this isn't the place for me to contribute **as you say**."*

Comment: @sha, [that's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384695/what-should-i-do-if-i-come-by-a-downvoted-answer-and-im-not-sure-if-it-has-issu?noredirect=1#comment1283340_384695) not the reason, it's explained in the FAQ.

Comment: See also the Tooltip feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85430/282094

Comment: As for *"I thought having possibly problematic answers reported to be reviewed was welcomed"*, that's what the 'not an answer' and 'very low quality' flags are for: they put bad answers in a queue for review, autocomments, more appropriate votes and deletion if the answer isn't improved. It still does not require a moderator to do so.

Comment: @Rob "you can use the comments on your question or answer to ask for suggestions for improvement" Please don't suggest doing that or do that, it is not an appropriate comment reason, everybody wants feedback & everybody who can comment knows they can comment. Valid is commenting to ask for clarification of another comment.

Comment: @philipxy, searching for the text you quoted turns up [this staff post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311266/282094) which opposes what you wrote in your comment. --- If you don't tell her, no need to tell me.

Comment: @Rob That post has nothing to do with the comments I mentioned that ask what problems a post has, it is about welcoming comments & moreover it says "**these comments are pretty much noise**". So I have no idea why you think it is relevant or contradicting me. Mods will erase comments asking for what may be wrong because that is implicit in the post having been posted so they too are just noise. Read mod Tinkeringbell's comments on this page. [Meta StackExchange > Help center > Privileges comment everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: "Suggestions for improvement" occurs twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know what's wrong with a question/answer/post, leave a comment on the post. Don't use a flag. Flags are not meant for that. That's what the moderator tells you in the reply.

The community can handle how to respond to your comment. It does not need a moderator's attention.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for. Even though I'm not sure I will keep contributing I hope it's useful for other people.

Comment: @gw0 do not let the discussion here put you off. My reading is that you were trying to be helpful but mis-understood.

Comment: @Mast Do note that this goes contrary to [old, established guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74559/369802) on the subject of leaving comments asking for an explanation of downvotes. Many of them are still flagged and deleted as 'no longer needed'.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell [This advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24501/269301), even older, but approved by Jeff himself, very established, referenced [in a FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560/269301), no longer holds. Old meta posts can be confusing.

Comment: @Mast fair enough, if you don't have the reputation to comment you can flag. Then a mod can go and comment for you then delete their own comment because it is not what comments are for... Or just decline the flag and save everyone some time. I will also go and entertain the SO mods with some flags asking them to downvotes posts for me now, as I don't have that privilege there either... I doubt that particular answer is the soundest advice out there, and I heavily recommend against using flags just to circumvent system restrictions like lacking privileges.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I'd recommend against using that answer as advice too, but it isn't marked as obsolete.

Comment: Please don't suggest doing that or do that, it is not an appropriate comment reason, everybody wants feedback & everybody who can comment knows they can comment. Valid is commenting to ask for clarification of another comment.

Answer (score 2):

Tl;Dr If you are not sure if a post has issues, don't flag it for moderator review.

---

If you need clarification about, including asking if there is something wrong with a third-party post, first try posting a comment directly under that post. You might also find helpful to follow that post as some authors edit theirs posts to make them clearer, improve / fix them, but don't leave a comment or don't mention the user who left the comment asking for clarification.

If the post is not clarified / fixed in a reasonable time, you might post a follow-up question after spending some time trying to figure it out by yourself if really there is something wrong with the post.

If you have enough reputation you might post a bounty to get attention to the question and perhaps asking for better answers. Unfortunately there isn’t any way to set a bounty to get attention to specific answers.

Please never ask for explanations about a single vote, no matter if it's upvote, downvote, a close vote, or a delete vote. This has already discussed in the past and mentioned in the question comments.

More specifically, never flag a post for asking moderators clarification on something done by a third party. You might flag your own posts that have being affected by a moderator action, like deletion or closing, asking why they took that action explaining why you require a specific explanation beyond what is already said in the linked help articles / FAQ in the notice.

Flagging a post for moderator review never should be done to ask moderators to review a post regarding its technical correctness, accuracy, language grammar, and spelling. While they are familiar with the site, please bear in mind that it's not required that they be top notch experts on everything that is on-topic on the site.

If you will regularly reviewing posts, please also check out the corresponding per-site Meta as there might be special requests and guidance about how to handle emerging situations.

***Note***: While it's possible to make questions about specific posts in Meta, please bear in mind that doing this might trigger [the meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Related

- [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560/289691)
- [What is the "meta effect"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/289691)